# Find Roslyn default nullable context

Tags: c#, roslyn, nullable-reference-types

We can use Roslyn (Microsoft CodeAnalysis) to get the [nullability context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.semanticmodel.getnullablecontext?view=roslyn-dotnet). But the `NullableContext` struct often indicates that the nullable context is inherited from the project default. In an analyzer, I thus need to determine the project default nullable context. I have not figured out a way to do this from the compilation object or the semantic model.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: How do you get the position properly to get the nullable context? The sourcespan is always  0 and therefore nullable context always returns false for all flags :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the project default, you can get it from [Compilation.Options.NullableContextOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpcompilationoptions.nullablecontextoption).

But as you correctly observed in your answer, asking the semantic model computes the effective value for you.

Answer (score 1):

I may have posted this prematurely, as I found a solution shortly after posting. The answer is that when NullableContext is set to Inherited, that is a flags value where the flag for warnings enabled is not set, so a context supporting non-nullable reference types is not enabled (that is, we have old style code). So, at least i don't need to figure out what the project default is.

More generally, one can test the flags as follows:

```
public static class NullableContextExtensions
    {
        private static bool IsFlagSet(NullableContext context, NullableContext flag) =>
            (context & flag) == flag;

        public static bool WarningsEnabled(this NullableContext context) =>
            IsFlagSet(context, NullableContext.WarningsEnabled);

        public static bool AnnotationsEnabled(this NullableContext context) =>
            IsFlagSet(context, NullableContext.AnnotationsEnabled);
    }
```

On the other hand, one might still want to know the project default, so if anyone posts the code for achieving that, I will mark it as the correct anwer.